How do I copy Migration Typescript files from code to build folder with NX
I have this folder structure in my nx workspace:
apps/
├── backend/
│   ├── webpack.config.js
│   └── src/
│       └── database/
│           └── migrations/
│               ├── X.ts
│               ├── Y.ts
│               └── ...

I build my NestJS Backend with webpack. Everything works except for compiling my migration ts files to js and then copying them into my dist folder. I don't import the migration files but instead load them dynamically with "Umzug" for my sequelize instance.
I already tried the CopyPlugin for my webpack config, but it only copies the ts files into my dist folder. And I also tried using a "prebuild" package.json script. But when I rebuild the project with nx, the js migration files get deleted from dist automatically and they were in the wrong path anyways.
